# Strange jQuery cycle2 error in slide transition to the last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-cycle

I have a website (http://file-new.com/client/vequity5/). The whole website is in the jQuery Malsup's Cycle2 plugin. Everything seems to be working fine and as expected except one little thing. When you click on the last page (contact) the slide transition has a little white flash. It's more pronounced in safari that any other browser but it's still visible almost any browser. My observation of the effect are leading me to the conclusion that it has to do something with the synchronization of the animation of the slides.

Any advice/thought will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it do this for you even after you let the whole thing load?  If I let it load fully, it works good for me on Chrome

Comment: Yes, it does. Chrome is handling it the best and it's almost invisible. Try Firefox though. Or Chrome on mobile device.